# How to load google-maps javascript in template only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using `google maps` javascript api, and would like to load the javascript file only on the page where the map is actually displayed.

When I load the maps within `<script>` in `index.html`, everything is fine.

```
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>...</script>
</body>
```

But when I move the script to the template that is to be included, it does not work:

maps.html:

```
<div id="google-map">
    ...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

controller:

```
var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), {
    center: location,
    zoom: 10
});
```

Result: `Error: google.maps is undefined`.

Question: how can I ensure the script is loaded only on the desired page, and that it is loaded before the instantiate in the `controller` takes place?

Comment: Please add a Fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

need to add script tag before div, hope this may works

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="google-map">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't change the problem.